# Why might Apache Tomcat not release the port on exit?

Tags: web-server, tomcat

I have an apache tomcat server which has recently stopped releasing the http-alt port when I shut it down. I've seen this behavior when developing client server programs, but Tomcat never seemed to have this problem before. As far as I know, nothing has changed.

Any suggestions as to what I can investigate would be appreciated. Is it possible for my servlets to prevent tomcat from shutting down correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the process is actually stopping.  The only way I can imagine for Tomcat to fail to release a port is if it is hung somehow in shutting down.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with a log4j library being deployed where it shouldn't. Apparently, that causes problems for tomcat. See the first issue: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html

Comment: That is to say, it was causing tomcat's shutdown to fail.